# Merge and plot multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Would like help to accomplish the following:

**Summary**

1. Re-index a data frame
2. Merge multiple data frames
3. Plot the new data frame based on a time column

**More Details**

I have a data set (raw_data) that looks like this:

```
id  timestamp       key             value
1   1576086899000   temperature     70
2   1576086899000   sleep           8
3   1576086899000   heartrate       65
4   1576086876000   temperature     72
5   1576086876000   sleep           7.5
6   1576086876000   heartrate       62
7   1576086866000   temperature     74
8   1576086866000   sleep           7.8
9   1576086866000   heartrate       64
```

I pivoted it using the following:

`df = rawdata.pivot(index='timestamp', columns='key', values='value')`

This made the index a timestamp value, and each column a key name with it's corresponding value.

Because each of the rows does not always contain a value for each key/value pair, I created a new data frame for the specific key, and dropped any NaN values:

`sleep_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': df.index, 'value': df.sleep}).dropna()`

This still kept the index as column timestamp, but created a duplicate column called time. I then formatted the time column as a year-month-day value with:

`sleep_df['date]' = pd.to_datetime(sleep_df['date'], unit='ms').map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Therefore, my resulting data set looks like for each of these tables looks like the following:

```
timestamp       date         sleep            
1576086899000   2020-04-05      8
1576086876000   2020-04-04     7.5
1576086866000   2020-04-03     7.8
```

My end goal would be to:

1. Merge each of these tables and plot them against the time column. I believe the index should be kept `timestamp` for this reason, because it can then merge values where the timestamp the data was recorded was the same.
2. In future analysis, I'd love to figure out if I could merge data based on the date rather than on the timestamp since some data may have not been recorded at the exact time. Would I have to make the index: "date" instead? I assume I'd have to make sure that there was only one entry for each individual date otherwise merging tables could get funky.
3. I *think* I figured out the plotting for this data. I made the index of the table to be the `date` field, and converted all the values to be type `int` and it plotted against the date just fine. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you for the help in advance, SO has been so great as a learning tool.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to plot the time series for each key, I would suggest not pivoting, separating dataframes and re-merging them. I would suggest working on the initial DataFrame directly, as you can draw a plot where each line represents a specific key, for instance with `seaborn`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": pd.date_range("2020-04-20 00:00:00", periods=8, freq="D"),
                   "key": ["temperature", "sleep", "heartrate", "temperature", "sleep", "heartrate", "temperature", "sleep"],
                   "value": [70, 8, 65, 72, 7.5, 62, 74, 7.8]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
g = sns.relplot(x="date", y="value", hue="key", kind="line", data=df)
g.fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

It is not necessary to index by `date`. 
Hope it helps.